Sharing file on Google drive using API or SDK
I want to share file on Google drive to others using API or SDK to save manual efforts. When I do it manually, I remove the access from the person I shared to after two weeks. With programming via API, I would like to know whether it is possible to remove access via API? Somebody said if I have a Google workspace, the API has the function of setting expiration date when sharing. However, I do not want to pay for the Google workspace if there is another workaround. Thanks a lot!
Any possible solution is welcome!

In your situation, how about using Google Apps Script and the time-driven trigger? When those are used, you can remove the permission at the time you want. But, I'm not sure whether this is included in your expected result. So, I proposed this as a comment.
